# How can I update the value of a field in a table to be a random number that's unique most of the time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
    [WordId]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NameId]        INT            NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordId] ASC)
);
```

I have a unique index on NameId

I am trying to update this table and change one column to a random number:

```
UPDATE Word SET NameId = ROUND(RAND()*2147483647,0)
```

I realize there is a very very small chance this will not work but it's actually failing every time even though the table has only a very small number of rows the update always fails and says there's a duplicate.

Can anyone tell me what's happening here and also suggest a way to update this table so that there's no duplicate values of NameId created most of the time.

Comment: I just tried your code without unique index on 20 rows and every result was the same value

Comment: you probably get many duplicates with this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating every NameId with same value, use `WHERE` statement to update only one row

EDIT: This should do the trick you are looking for, NewId() generates new id for each row

```
UPDATE Word SET NameId = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 2147483647)
```

Comment: I need to update 500 rows with every one different.  Not sure what you mean about use the WHERE statement unless I issue that 500 times.  Need to find some way to loop through the rows I think.

Comment: Sorry, It is early in the morning in here and it took a minute for me to sort out you want this, I edited my answer and hope it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. For testing I would like to test this out on another table first.  How can I create another table from the Word table that has all the word data?  I tried "Create table word2 as select * from word" but this doesn't work.

Comment: This is worthy of new question, but use : SELECT * INTO dbo.WordTesting FROM dbo.Word

Answer (score 0):

How many rows do you have?  It could be a case of the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Have you tried doing this:

```
SELECT ROUND(RAND()*2147483647,0) FROM Word
```

Do the numbers really need to be pseudo-random? You could use [row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms186734.aspx) to make them increment.

Comment: I have about 500 rows in the table. I really would like to make them random if possible and not sequential.  Hynek commented that I was updating the rows with the same value. Could this be the problem? I thought it would go through each row and use a different value but now I am not sure. I want each row to have a different value. Thanks